# Decode statement in oracle sums values of result

Tags: oracle

I have a decode statement in Oracle:

```
DECODE(a.part,'0001',NVL(b.q1,0),
              '0002',NVL(b.q1,0),
              '0003',NVL(b.q1,0),
              '0004',NVL(b.q1,0),0) q1,
```

The condition is if any of the criteria "0001" to "0004" is met the `b.q1` will be the value of `q1` else 0.

My problem is when "0001" and "0002" is met the value of `q1` should be the sum of the two conditions met. Does DECODE add the value of the result? What I want to achieve is if one of the criteria is met take the value of `b.q1` and assign to `q1`. I am thinking  of an OR statement in an IF-ELSE condition.

Comment: Can you show the entire query?  All `DECODE()` should be doing is a series of if-else logic.  It should not be summing anything, unless your query is doing that.

Comment: Sample Data with expected results, will give us a better clarity.

Comment: No, decode doesn't sum or add two values, the issue is somwhere else in your code, not in decode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECODE() is a transforming function. It spits out one row for each row submitted. It is analogous to the more general CASE function.

To aggregate values you need an aggregating function, in this circumstance SUM()...

```
sum(DECODE(a.part,'0001',NVL(b.q1,0),
          '0002',NVL(b.q1,0),
          '0003',NVL(b.q1,0),
          '0004',NVL(b.q1,0),0)) as q1
```

Or, with CASE here because it is less typing:

```
sum( case
       when a.part in ('0001','0002','0003','0004')
            and b.q1 is not null
       then b.q1
       else 0 end) as q1
```

You only included a snippet of your query. It is quite possible that you will need to make other changes to accommodate the aggregation. Specifically you will need to add a GROUP by clause to your query which references all the non-aggregated columns in your query's projection.